# Delphi - Pegando valores das propriedades com GetPropValue()

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Estou usando a função `GetPropValue()` do Delphi para pegar valores de  determinadas propriedades de alguns objetos do tipo `TControl`. Tudo funciona corretamente quando pego valores de propriedades simples, como por exemplo `Value`, `Opacity`, etc, mas, como estou usando firemonkey existem algumas propriedades extendidas, como por exemplo, `RotationCenter`, ela possui `RotationCenter.X` e `RotationCenter.Y`, ou mesmo as propriedades de texto dentro de `TextSettings`, nestas propriedades com subpriedades não consigo pegar os valores.

Neste exemplo abaixo consigo pegar os valores corretamente:

```
if IsPublishedProp(Componente_cc, 'Value') then
  editValue.Text := GetPropValue(Componente_cc, 'Value', true);
```

Onde `Componente_cc: TControl;` e é criado de forma dinâmica, também pode ser qualquer tipo de componente do Firemonkey (até aqui tudo certo, tudo funciona).

Já quando preciso usar da forma abaixo, não funciona.

```
if IsPublishedProp(Componente_cc, 'RotationCenter.X') then
  editRotationCenterX.Text := GetPropValue(Componente_cc, 'RotationCenter.X', true);
```

Alguem sabe um forma de pegar essas propriedades extendidas por esta função?